# Does a compiler that compiles to machine code need to be written in assembly?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, low-level, machine-code

Excluding compilers that convert one high-level language to another, does any compiler that compiles to machine code need to be written in assembly?

Comment: No, why do you think that is needed?

Comment: Must the robots that build cars be made out of cars?  No. Many languages can write files with bits in them.  Any langauge that can write memory or a file with bits in it can be used to generate machine code (which is just some bits in memory or a file).

Comment: look at tiny cc as an example of straight to machine code compiling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source code for a compiler does not need to be written in assembly.  For example, (a good portion) of the CPython compiler (well, technically interpreter) is written in C:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpython

In the very beginning, before there were compilers, the very first compiler did have to be written in assembly.  But then someone used this compiler to compile their own compiler.  Then someone else used this compiler to compile their own compiler.  And so on and so forth.

This brings up the concept of "bootstrapping".  A bootstrapping compiler is one that is written in the language it intends to compile.  The clang compiler can compile C++ code, but the compiler itself is written in C++!  How does this work?  Well the very first clang compiler was compiled by a different compiler (g++ probably).  After the clang compiler was mature enough, it was able to compile its own code.  Now, any changes made to the clang compiler can be recompiled by the clang compiler into another clang compiler!  Neat, huh?

Comment: I've heard about this sort of thing before, but I haven't taken a compilers course yet. I've always thought it was very interesting (and for now, confusing) that some compilers could compile themselves. I'm still looking for a good introductory course to compiler construction. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Compilers are a joy.  If you can't find a compiler course to take, I'd still recommend picking up a book and playing around with them.  There is just so much going on in the background quickly and quietly that we take for granted.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler is not a special, magical program. If you squint at it, a compiler is just a program that turns one text file into another text file (well, okay, a binary file).

There is only one constraint about what language a program can be implemented in. If you're writing a program in a language, that language has to already have a compiler or interpreter implemented. Therefore, the first compiler/interpreter for language X cannot be written in X. (If you want to be able to use it, at least.) But this isn't special to compilers/interpreters; you can't usefully write anything in X until someone has implemented X.